# How to filter categories based on URL on category.php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a category template on my WordPress site that i want to use for all categories, but i having problems to filter the posts using WP_Query.

lets say i have a category named News WordPress will generate the following url for me: example.com/category/news

How can i filter the posts in WP_Loop to only show posts from the news category?

This is what i have:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged,'cat' => $category[0]->id);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But i'm pretty sure this is not the way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the slug of a current page, as mentioned in the link below. Then query posts with that category slug.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42117/how-to-retrieve-the-slug-of-current-page